# Using Bootstrap via less with MVC4

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm new to Bootstrap and Less and struggling..

I'm trying to copy in samples from the following site, but they don't look as they should. What am I doing wrong?
http://bootsnipp.com/snipps/credit-card-payment-form-2

I've installed 'Bootstrap Less Source' via Nuget and also 'Bundle Transformer: LESS' to turn the Less into CSS.
I've also modified my MVC BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));
bundles.Add("~/Content/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/site.less",
                    "~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.less");
```

I've updated my view to contain the following:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the HTML being rendered by the `@Styles.Render` calls?

Comment: How does it not look right? You need to provide more information.

Comment: I expect https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62538279/Help/9-30-2013%205-07-46%20PM.png
But get https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62538279/Help/9-30-2013%205-08-54%20PM.png

Comment: The @Styles.Render puts in:
<link href="/Content/site.less" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.less" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my problem was to do with the version of Bootstrap.
I was using v3.0.0.0 whereas the samples that I was looking at were in v2.3.2

As soon as I added the following link, everything worked.

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Thanks